# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}=\infty$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am working on an asymptotic analysis question from a data structures past paper, and I need to show that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}=\infty$$

Could I have a **hint** for working out how to show this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use L'hopital's rule on the limit since it's in an indeterminate form.

Comment: I have tried to use your hint, but am struggling to make progress.  Let $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = (\log n)^2$ (where we are working base 2).  Note that $g(n) = (\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)})^2$.  Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\ln(n)\cdot (\ln2)^{-2}} = 0 \not= \infty.$  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You should have $g'(n) = \frac{2\ln(n)}{n(\ln(2))^2}$. $$((\ln(n))^2)' =2(\ln(n))(\ln(n))' = \frac{2\ln(n)}{n}$$

Comment: Of course.  You correctly identified my mistake.  I have solved the problem now.  :)

Answer (score 2):

note that $ log(n) \leq n^\alpha $ for any $\alpha >0$ for instance chose $\alpha = 1/4$ now apply comparison test

Alter: Use L'Hospitals Rule

Comment: How can I show that $\log n \leq n^\alpha \space \forall \alpha \gt 0$?

Comment: @CKKOY Do you know $n \geq \log(n)$.

Comment: @user222031: Yes, I do know that fact.  :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65202/how-to-prove-log-n-n

Comment: @CKKOY refer above mentioned post

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\sqrt n}{\log n}\to +\infty \implies \frac{n}{(\log n)^2} \to +\infty$$
And you can have many ways to prove the first part.